# PAC Learning LTFs with random classification noise and membership query

Tags: machine-learning

How would one design an algorithm to PAC learn linear threshold functions with random classification noise using membership queries?

More formally, the learner has access to unlabeled examples from an unknown distribution $D$ on $X$ and membership query access to the target concept.